Dart ffi load DynamicLibrary with dependencies
I've got a precompiled .so library for Linux (x64) which I have generated a ffi interface for using ffigen, all good so far. When I try to load it using:
var libraryPath = path.join(Directory.current.absolute.path, 'lib', 'native', 'lib64', 'mylib.so');

final dylib = ffi.DynamicLibrary.open(libraryPath);

I get the error:
ArgumentError: Failed to load dynamic library 'libsecond.so.0'

The file 'libsecond.so.0' exists in the same directory as the mylib.so and verified that it exists at runtime but it won't load the library.
What else do I need to do to load the lib? It relies on a few external .so libs which are all present in the same directory.

I could assume that ffi.DynamicLibrary.open() is using the following function of libdl:
void *dlopen(const char *filename, int flags);

If you don't give absolute path, then dlopen() search the library file from certain directories. See man page for more details.
You can try it by setting the wanted directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, for example:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/native/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

If the shared library requires another shared libraries, then all those are searched similar way.
ldd command can be used for checking is everything ok.
For example, if you get "not found", then search path is not correct:
    $ ldd /lib/native/lib64/mylib.so           
    libsecond.so.0 => not found                
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb6be0000)
    $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/native/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    $ ldd /lib/native/lib64/mylib.so           
    libsecond.so.0 => /lib/native/lib64/libsecond.so.0                
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb6be0000)    

